# GraphQL Subscription Not Updating Properly in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I'm creating a website to list events with the ability to create, update and delete events.  I'm using a subscription prop in my  component to connect with AWS app sync, but the update isn't working properly.

When I subscribe to changes, I update my list of events in my state, and then display events from the state.
A component appears for the new event but does not populate it with any data.
It appears immediately and I'm wondering if its not waiting for the database to populate it?

//  / and place I am displaying events

```
render(){
        return(

            <Connect id="connect" 
                subscription={graphqlOperation(subscriptions.onCreateEvent)}
                onSubscriptionMsg={(prev, newEvent) => {
                    const events = [...this.state.events, newEvent]
                    this.setState({events:events});
                    return prev;
                    }
                 }

                query={graphqlOperation(listEvents)}>       
                {({ data: { listEvents }, loading, error }) => {
                    if (error) return (<h3>Error</h3>);
                    if (loading || !listEvents) return (<h3>Loading...</h3>);
                    return (
                        <div id="eventloader">
                            {this.displayEvents()}
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Connect>

        );
    }
```

// function to display events

```
displayEvents () {
        return this.state.events.map((event, i) => (
            <Col md={4} key={i}>
                <Event 
                    openModal={this.openModal}
                    admin={false}
                    id={event.id}
                    title={event.name} 
                    date={event.date}
                    description={event.description} />
            </Col>
            )
```

Thanks for any help.